# After promoting to production - Scope in access token always none after consent granted

Tags: docusignapi

I'm calling account.docusign.com/oauth/auth, the scopes list is

```
account_read%20impersonation%20organization_read%20user_read
```

I can see the granted application in my profile -> Connected Apps page. And when I attempt to use it with my API integration the date updates.

But no matter what the access token returned by account.docusign.com contains 'scope': None. And every API call I attempt results in a 401 response.

The account I am impersonating is a 'DS Admin'. I updated my RSA key, account ID, and user ID to the production values.

Everything worked in the demo account. What is the issue here?

Expecting the scope field in the access token to contain the requested and consented scopes.

actual code:

```
from docusign_admin import ApiClient, UsersApi

SCOPES = ["account_read", "impersonation", "organization_read", "user_read"]
# get access token
api_client = ApiClient()
api_client.set_base_path('account.docusign.com')
api_client.set_oauth_host_name('account.docusign.com')

# get_private_key returns the private key as bytes as required by library
private_key = get_private_key('secrets/docusign_private_key').encode("ascii")

# request_jwt_user_token sets the Authorization token header. I've also tried setting it manually with a fresh api_client object
response = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
    client_id=SECRETS['docusign_integration_key'],
    user_id=SECRETS['docusign_user_id'],
    oauth_host_name='account.docusign.com',
    private_key_bytes=private_key,
    expires_in=4000,
    scopes=SCOPES
)
# create admin api UsersApi object using api_client with bearer token set
api_client.host = 'https://api.docusign.net/management'
user_api = UsersApi(api_client=api_client)
organization_id = 'x'
user_id = 'x'
user_details = user_api.get_user_ds_profile(organization_id=organization_id, user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: What endpoint are you calling? do you have an organizationID ? accountID? did you update these values to prod too?

Comment: @InbarGazit I am calling to the admin API. The org ID was updated with the production ID from the 'account profile' page. and the account ID was updated with the production 'API Account ID'

Comment: Is the list of scopes both in the consent URL as well as in the JWT request? two different places?

Comment: Yes, it is in the jwt creator function, and the consent request url

Comment: Can you add the exact code you're running to the question? If you're trying to add a user - I may know what this is

Comment: The user_id below ('x') is it the same value as the user above (SECRETS['docusign_user_id'])? 
If not - how did you get this other user_id ?

Comment: @InbarGazit Ideally when calling get_user_ds_profile the user_id could be any user id in the org. But I still get 401 if using the same value as SECRETS['docusign_user_id'].

Comment: @InbarGazit Do you know if its required to set up an authorized application to impersonate any DS Admin in prod? My companies docusign account does not have 'Docusign Admin' enabled so I cannot create an authorized application

Comment: Hmmm, then how do you have an organization and organizationId? if you don't have DocuSign Admin enabled? I'm confused

Comment: I got the org ID from the Account Profile page. I'm starting to think that the admin api is only enabled for "Enterprise Pro with the Organization Management Add-On" accounts. 

The eSignature API works as expected.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of where you get the org ID from?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3OKBP1B.png

Comment: ok, now take this value, construct a URL like this:
https://admin.docusign.com/organization/{{orgId}}/dashboard and see if this works. You can try the same thing in demo, with a URL like this (and the value in demo):
https://admindemo.docusign.com/organization/{{orgId}}/dashboard

Comment: You may need to get the Admin feature to be able to use this, I didn't realize you can even have an orgID without it

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the account/organization in production does not have the feature for Admin Management.
While almost all features are available in the developer account for developers to use (also known as "demo") in production it depends on the account, feature plans, and what SKUs it is using. You may need to [talk to DocuSign sales](https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales) to get this feature added to your account (may cost extra).

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation scope is only valid with the JWT oauth flow. Which oauth flow are you using?

Please edit / update your question with the additional information

Comment: I am using the JWT oauth flow